# TikZ node positioning on edge parameter/label

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I wonder if there exists a trick to position a graph node (relative), based on a parameter (label?) of an edge leading to it?

I mean a kind of time diagram, i.e. for example I have a timed automat, where both the node processing and the change of state along the edge needs time. I would like to place automatically the  next node on the graph at the correct time position on the time axis, corresponding to the position of the previous node+processing time in the previous node+transition time to the next node.
(much like in networking : processing time in a router plus delivery time to the next router)

Thanks for any idea in advance

Janos

Comment: With calc you could use ($(node.north east)!\t!(node.south east)$) to specify a point on the east side of the node where \t expands to a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Could you give/draw some examples?

Comment: Without some more concrete example(s), I'm afraid this looks unclear.